# [viewcontroller retain]: message sent to deallocated instance error after dismiss viewcontroller

Tags: objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uicollectionview, apple-tv, avplayerviewcontroller

I my application I am presenting viewcontroller(detailsview) after select item in collectionview:

```
[self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:^{


                }];
```

From the new viewcontroller I launch avplayer after that I am dismissing player then the (detailsview)viewcontroller and coming back to home view controller. Here app is crashing and giving error as [detailsviewController retain]: message sent to deallocated instance. This I am doing in apple TV. Dismissing controllers using menu action.

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{ 

 if([assetType isEqualToString:@“MOV”] ||[assetType isEqualToString:@"PRG”] )
            {
                    // Asset landing page

                    NSMutableArray *assets=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"ViewAll",nil];
                    [assets addObjectsFromArray:self->allAssetsArray];
                    NSDictionary *SelectedAsset=[self->allAssetsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
                    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];

                    DetailsViewController  *detailView =(DetailsViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];

                    OnDemandAssetModel * assetModel=[[OnDemandAssetModel alloc]init];
                    assetModel.identifier=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"id"];
                    assetModel.assetCategory=@"";//[category objectForKey:@"name"];
                    assetModel.assetId=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"assetId"];
                    assetModel.assetName=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"movieName"];
                    assetModel.assetDuration=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"runningTime"];
                    assetModel.assetGenre=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"genre"];
                    assetModel.assetCategoryType=@"SVoD";
                    assetModel.assetDirector=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"director"];
                    assetModel.assetActors=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"cast"];
                    assetModel.assetCC=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@""];

                    assetModel.assetAvailableUntil=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"availableUntil"];
                    assetModel.assetRating=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"rating"];
                    assetModel.assetPosterPath=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"movieImage"];
                    assetModel.assetContentType=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"movieType"];
                    assetModel.assetDescription=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"description"];
                    assetModel.assetReleasedYear=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"releasedYear"];
                    assetModel.subscriptionStatus=[SelectedAsset objectForKey:@"subscription"];

                    detailView.assetModel=assetModel;
                    detailView.selectedAssetID=assetModel.assetId;
                    detailView.selectedIndex=[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexPath.row+1 inSection:0];
                    detailView.identifier=assetModel.identifier;

                    [self showViewController:detailView sender:nil];

                  //  [self presentViewController:detailView animated:YES completion:^{


                   // }];
            }


}
```

Comment: Show code where you add viewcontroller with avplayer

Comment: If you are using ARC, the application will crash or give error.

Comment: Yes i am using ARC.

Comment: hi piotri i added code please check once.

Comment: Hi Mahboob how can i comeout from this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to deal with the crash by saving detailView to an instance variable. Right now it's just a local variable so it will get released when it's not in use anymore.

Add `@property (strong, nonatomic) DetailsViewController *detailsView;` to your `@interface`, and in the code you posted change the alloc on the detailsView to:

```
self.detailView = (DetailsViewController*)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsViewController"];
```

Comment: i did it not helps me